# Using external GPS on browser

Tags: windows, browser, gps, external

I have the Cable GPS with USB interface (SiRF Star IV).

I want my browser to use my external GPS instead of my location from my laptop/prodiver.

On a browser I want to see the locaation of my external GPS and not my location of my internal laptop GPS or internet provider GPS. How do I change this?

I am still wondering if there is a different way to do this without GPSDirect since is has some costs with it.(I tried the evaluation mode but couldn't find any way to get it to browser). And I couldn't find any guide how to do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I am still wondering how to get it with GPSDirect to browser since I don't see how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do depend on the location services provided by the operating system – they have no business containing drivers for thousands of different GNSS receivers.

So, to change that, you'll need to install the windows drivers for your GPS module, and convince windows to use that. (I don't know how that would work, though.)

Comment: I have the gps installed on my laptop and on a program I can use it via the serial com port. But now I want to use that one and I don't know how to do that

Comment: @WillemYiex - You will be hard pressed to get a browser to use a serial connection to a GPS given that, browsers don’t actually use GPS, but geolocations to identify your location. Geolocation is close enough and probably more accurate then the GPS you want to use.

Comment: The problem is that we work with boats who their gps is from their provides and shows somewhere different, so thats why I want that the browser takes the external gps and not the provider's gps.

Comment: @WillemYiex as said, you need a Windows Driver for your GPS module that supports the Windows Location API, i.e., which offers the GPS fix as location to Windows, which in turns offers it to applications. I've got none experience with that whatsoever, but maybe https://www.gpssensordrivers.com/ is what you need.

Comment: you're asking the wrong person. I gave you what I knew.